# "I don't have what to do/where to put it"

Tags: where

Lately I've heard a couple people using the words "what" and "where" in a strange way.

They would say things like: "I don't have what to do" or "I don't have where to put it".

I'm pretty sure this is wrong, but hearing multiple people saying it made me doubt.

Am I right that this is simply wrong and they should say: "I don't have anything to do" and "I don't have anywhere to put it" instead?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong in formal British English, and I've never come across it in the US, Canada, Australia or NZ or any common British dialects, though it is possible that they're speaking an unusual dialect.

Comment: They are Lithuanian, so I guess it's probably a literal translation from that language.